# Use special objects of xy-pic with beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, xy-pic

When I try to use the general format for labels (cf. xyguide, §2.2) together with beamer overlays, the part that should show up later isn't formatted properly. I guess, beamer doesn't convert the `*` properly. What can I do? See the code below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Madrid}
  \usecolortheme{seahorse}
  \setbeamercovered{covered}
  \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[\xymatrix@=1.5em{
*++[o][F]{C} \only<+->{\ar@/^/[r]^{\alpha\rho}} & 
\uncover<.->{*++[o][F]{Z}} \only<.->{\ar@/^/[l]^{100\%}}
}\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's caused by the `\uncover` and grouping of the following expression. Without it, it works - so perhaps omit uncovering piecewise, or make it differently. The syntax works:

```
\begin{frame}
  \[\xymatrix@=1.5em{
    *++[o][F]{C} \only<+->{\ar@/^/[r]^{\alpha\rho}} & 
    *++[o][F]{Z} \only<.->{\ar@/^/[l]^{100\%}}
  }\]
\end{frame}
```

I would use [TikZ](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz) overlays instead. I guess, when the good old `xypic` package has been developed, beamer overlays didn't exist yet. If you would like to test it with TikZ, just extend your question to be open for a TikZ way, and we'll try.

[image: xy diagram in beamer]

Comment: Let's test that. Nevertheless, I have not used TikZ before. So maybe you have to explain it a bit. Does the whole thing have to be changes or can it stay basically as it is?

Comment: Just one extra question: This means there is no "easy" way to somehow "mask" the "*" or something?